I want to switch to a different window, using java and selenium, but the second window buffers continuously
I am developing an automation script using java and selenium. When I click on a button it opens a new window which buffers continuously and an alert popup is there. Until I accept the alert popup the window buffers, when I click on Ok then window is loaded.Now the thing is using window handles method, selenium is not able to identify the second window as it is not loaded.
I tried adding delay in the code before using get.windowhandles() method, but nothing works.
how can I switch to this window?

without the handle, you can't switch the driver to it.  Try using other browsers, as I'm pretty sure one of them will set a handle with a local context before URL loads.   What you describe is pretty strange behavior.  Not sure how they display an alert before anything loads.  Can you include markup/scripts of the launching window?  (and confirm that you are calling "driver.getWindowHandles();" ?   Include code you've tried.)

using a webdriverwait with the new expected condition of numberOfWindowsToBe might help, too:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe(int)

Thanks for the suggestions, there was a problem with website. Now I am able to switch the window

If you are using Chrome driver you could try to disable pop-up in options
ChromeOptions options  = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");

